# Where did Microsoft.Extensions.Compilation.Abstractions go after DNX

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dnx

I have been working on migrating a DNX project into aspnet core 2.0 project. While doing so, i have hit roadblock.

The code uses `IMetadataReference` from 
 `Microsoft.Extensions.Compilation.Abstractions` lib for reading assemblies metadata. With DNX being obsolete now, i could not find what `Microsoft.Extensions.Compilation.Abstractions` has been changed to now.

i have been looking in history and commits for aspnet on github but it does not provide any clue. while the dnx history provides details only till `Microsoft.Extensions.Compilation.Abstractions` and nothing after that.

Comment: _With DNX being obsolete now_... **now** is a pretty soft term for something that's been deprecated for 2 years, before even ASP.NET Core 1.0 was released. Try the ASP.NET Core annocements repository https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/milestones and click on one of the milestones, they list breaking changes between the versions

Comment: @Tseng i'd agree, *now* does not sound appropriate here. Also, Thanks for the link but i have already been through that list and not much help there for my issue. Last info about the lib i mentioned was 2 years ago after that nothing on that. i guess, i'll have to go through commits to find out or if anybody already know about this?

Comment: I did a quick Google search and found an abstract class, [`MetadataReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.metadatareference?view=roslyn-dotnet) in the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` namespace. I am not sure if that is equivalent to what you are looking for, though.

Comment: Why do you need `IMetadataReference `? It contains only `Name` property